# react.js - how to add element on success in dynamically generated button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have dynamically generated component with textfields and buttons. Each button do the ajax request. It's all working fine. However, I want to display the success message or error message on button itself, adding some icon on it. This is where I got stuck. I setup the flag and change the state, but it will change on all the buttons as expected. I also tried to change the current target, but the reference didn't work in success callback. Can someone please help me with this.

```
    const FormGroup = ({index, type, field, value, onChange, spinner, isLoading, error, buttonType, brandList, handleBrandConfiguration, checkAvailability, handleCaseType, options, handlerRemoveItem})=> {
  return(
    <div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label>{index}</label>
        <input type="text"
          name={field}
          className="form-control"
          value={value}
          onChange={onChange}
          />
          <select className="form-control" defaultValue="" onChange={handleBrandConfiguration}>
            <option value="">Please select brand</option>
            {brandList}
          </select>
        <select className="form-control" defaultValue="" onChange={handleCaseType}>
          <option value="">Please select case template</option>
          {options}
        </select>
        <button
          type={buttonType}
          className={classname(isLoading ? error ? "button button-danger" : "button button-success" : error ? "button button-danger" : "button button-primary")}
          onClick={checkAvailability}>
          <i className={classname(spinner ? error ? '': "fa fa-spinner fa-spin": '')}></i> {isLoading ? error ? 'Not Found' :<i className="fa fa-check fa-2" aria-hidden="true"></i> : error ? 'Not Found': 'Check Availability'}</button>
        <input
          type="button"
          className="button button-danger"
          value="Remove Item"
          onClick={handlerRemoveItem}/>
        </div>
      </div>
  );
};
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post a a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: not sure what you're saying.. does `error` not come back? How are you checking for success / error and what do they come back with?

Comment: That was my initial attempt setting up flag for each condition. For instance if I get success I have setup one flag and if there is error and I got another error flag. This is not a good way but I just used that for testing. I should have removed it. Sorry for making it confusing. What I am trying to do is when I get success I want to add an icon in my button but if i get error, i want to add another error icon on the same button. Issue is that they dynamically generated component, i'm not sure how to change in current button.
Thank you for looking at it.

Comment: Can you add some snippet for how are you using FormGroup constant

Comment: Hi @bennygenel I have written a small snippet here. [link[(https://codepen.io/mesmerize86/pen/dzLQaE?editors=1111). For testing I have used if condition where as it should be an ajax call. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move your `checkAvailability` and result of api request to `FormControl` component you can set error and success for single component.

**For Example:**

```
class FormGroup extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      availabilityResult: null
    };
  }
  callApi(username){
    return(axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/' + username));
  }
  onChange(e){
    this.setState({
      itemCode: e.target.value
    });
  }

  checkAvailability(e){
    const username = this.state.itemCode;
    let currentValue = e.currentTarget.value;
    //ajax call goes here
    this.callApi(username).then(response => {
      const login = response.data.login;
      this.setState({
        availabilityResult: (login === 'mesmerize86')
      });
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {index, field, value, handleRemoveItem} = this.props;
    let inputState = '';
    if (this.state.availabilityResult === true) inputState = 'button-success';
    else if (this.state.availabilityResult === false) inputState = 'button-danger';

    return(
      <div className="form form-inline">
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>{index}</label>
          <input type="text"
            name={field}
            className="form-control"
            value={value}
            onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
          />
          <input
            type="button"
            className={`button button-primary ${inputState}`}
            value="Check Availability"
            onClick={this.checkAvailability.bind(this)} />
            <input
              type="button"
              className="button button-danger"
              value="Remove Item"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        )    
      }
    }


    class Main extends React.Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          rowList : [],
          itemCodes: [],
          itemCode: ''
        }
      }
      handlerAddRow(){
        const rowList = this.state.rowList.concat(FormGroup);
        this.setState({ rowList });
      }      
      handleRemoveItem(){
        console.log('remove Item');
      }      
      render(){
        const rowList = this.state.rowList.map((row, index) => {
          return (<FormGroup key={index} index={index+1} field={`"itemCode_"${index}`} />);
        });

        return(
          <div className="container">
            <input type="button" value="Add a row" className="button button-primary" onClick={this.handlerAddRow.bind(this)} />    <i class="fa fa-spinner" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            {rowList}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Thank You @bennygenel. It's all working now. I should have done state component instead of stateless component. Cheers,